# Como puedo copiar el valor ASCII a un int en C?

Tags: c, string

por ejemplo, teniendo el siguiente código mi intención es operar para obtener un numero de indice

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
 char mes[2]= {"02"};
 int numero;
 numero = (int)mes;
    char *strings[]={ "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Ago", "Sep","Oct", "Nov", "Dic"};

  printf("%s\n", strings[numero - 1]);   

    return 0;
}
```

en el ejemplo deberia imprimir `Feb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues usar la función [`atoi( )`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) ( de `<stdlib.h>` ), que se encarga precisamente de eso: interpreta el contenido de una cadena y devolver un `int`.

No obstante, hay que modificar tu código, puesto que `atoi( )` espera una cadena **terminada en 0**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void ) {
  char *mes= "02"; // <-- Cambiamos esto.
  int numero;

  numero = atoi( mes );

  char *strings[]={ "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Ago", "Sep","Oct", "Nov", "Dic"};

  printf( "%s\n", strings[numero - 1] );   

  return 0;
}
```

Al compilarlo y ejecutarlo, obtenemos la salida deseada:

> Feb

Esta función no es la mas *segura*, puesto que **no podemos comprobar posibles errores**; por ejemplo,

```
atoi( "aa" );
```

Nos devolvería un `0`.

Dispones de funciones similares pero mas potentes, tales como [`strtol( )` y `strtoll( )`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html), con valores de retorno `long int` y `long long int` respectivamente, con soporte para distintas bases numéricas y que nos permiten detectar errores durante la interpretación.